# How do I hide the Next anchor in my custom Nivo nav if it has less than six images?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, slider, nivo-slider

I'm working on a custom navigation thumbnail slider for the Nivo Slider Jquery plugin.

I'm trying to hide the Next anchor when the thumbnail slider contains less than or equal to 6 thumbnails.

`.nivo-control` is the anchor the thumbnail images are children of, and they are all children of `.items`.

I've already tried:

```
        if  ($('.items').children('.nivo-control') <= 6) {
            $('a.next').css('display', 'none !important');
        } else {
            // Do something
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
    if  ($('.items').children('.nivo-control').length <= 6) {
        $('a.next').css('display', 'none !important');
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
```

Comment: This works! Amazing fast response too! Totally forgot the length part. I'll mark this as accepted as soon as the time restriction clears!

Comment: Just wondering (since I am a jQuery beginner too): why are we not using size(); here? I know the results will probably be the same, but I was wondering why to use length(); instead of size(); here?

Comment: length is native javascript call, since jquery selector queries returns an array and length is an array method, my guess is it's also faster since it's native, size() is a jquery method.

Comment: I just realized your original answer was right; OP was looking for counts equal to or greater than 6 existing elements.  Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
   if  ($('.items').children('.nivo-control').length <= 6) {
        $('a.next').css('display', 'none !important');
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
```

Comment: This would also work! I tried to vote you up but I don't have enough rep yet :{ Thanks dude!